# how to style font color of selected Text which is contained under 2 or more html tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- User selects a **Text** then choose color from color-piker
  control.
- on click event of the save button from the color-picker, I want to
  change the color of the selected text, still keeping the span tag of
  *italic*, **bold** and **a** classes but not the textColor classes.

[image to show the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YvKO.jpg)

```js
private _addColor = () => {
   const range: any = window.getSelection()!.getRangeAt(0)
   const fragment = range.extractContents()

   // this.state.textColor is set by color-picker control
   const textClassName = getTextClassNames(textStyle(this.state.textColor))
   const span = document.createElement('span')

   span.className = textClassName.textColor
   this._clearNestedColorStyle(fragment)
   span.appendChild(fragment)
   range.insertNode(span)
}

private _clearNestedColorStyle(node: any) {
  node.childNodes.forEach((child: any) => {
    if (child.nodeType === 1) {
      if (child!.className.substring(0, 'textColor'.length) === 'textColor') {
        if (child.hasChildNodes()) {
          this._clearNestedColorStyle(child)
          this._removeChildNode(child)
        } else {
          child.innerHTML = child.innerText
        }
      } else {
        if (child.hasChildNodes()) {
          this._clearNestedColorStyle(child)
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

private _removeChildNode = (node: any) => {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
  while (node.firstChild) {
    fragment.appendChild(node.firstChild)
  }
  node.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, node)
}
```

```html
<span>
  It is a (selection start) long <span class="textColor-448" >established </span> fact that a 
  <span class="italic"> reader</span> will be <span class="bold">distracted</span> by the 
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="link"> readable</a> <span class="textColor-456" >content of 
  a page (selection end) when looking </span> at its layout.
</span>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that altering the DOM manually in react is an antipattern, you should alter jsx